# String equals method

Tags: java, string

Now this is a very silly problem which I'm not able to solve.
I have a `String address="someurl/id/"`. I have another `String newAddress="someurl/"+id+"/"`.

Now when I perform

```
 if(address.equals(newAddress))
```

The condition is not coming true. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I'm getting the id from shared preferences, so it is definitely an integer. Here is my Log

```
 07-02 21:34:49.556    4098-4185/com.parkwheels V/destAdress﹕ http://ovunque.in/api/v1/users/25/
 07-02 21:34:49.556    4098-4185/com.parkwheels V/putAddress﹕ http://ovunque.in/api/v1/users/25/
```

Comment: what is that you are expecting as output?

Comment: It should match the strings and send an HttpPut request.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case you use the value "id", in the second, whatever the id variable contains as value. So unless id=="id", the two strings are not equal.

Comment: the id the first string is a number only. same as the other id

Comment: So it's not, according to your code there is no number in the first address, it's teh string "someurl/id/".

Comment: The edited question is not clearer. Just do System.out.println(address), System.out.println(newAddress) and compare.

Answer (score 4):

Well, unless the variable `id` is a String that contains the value "id", the Strings are not equal.

For example, if `id` is an `int` whose value is 300, the value of `String newAddress="someurl/"+id+"/"` is `"someurl/300/"` which is not equal to `"someurl/id/"`.

Comment: The String address is address="http://ovunque.in/api/v1/users/25/" . And the value of variable id=25. So the String newAddress="http://ovunque.in/api/v1/users/"+25+"/"

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out newAddress and seeing what it looks like?  Is your id variable a double?  It might be putting 25.0 in there instead if just 25.

Comment: I'm getting the id from shared preferences. so its and integer only.